# D-Link DMC-1002 Management Module Password Reset

Tags: hardware, root, fiber, password-reset, d-link

We just purchased a D-Link DMC-1000 media converter chassis with a DMC-1002 management module.  Connected to the module through a COM port and PuTTy and changed the root password.  Subsequent login attempts fail now and trying to reset the password (the manual says to hit the escape sequence 3-4 times during bootup) do not work - there is no response to the action.

Anyone have any ideas?  I've got a support job open with D-Link but they're saying it may be up to 24 hours before we hear from them.

EDIT: From D-Link for if anyone ever needs this in the future:

Here are the procedures to enter the backdoor system.
1.Power off the chassis. 
2.Connect the console port correctly.
3.Press the "Esc" key in your keyboard, hold it and not release.
4.Power on the chassis
5.When you see all the LEDs on the chassis light up, release the "Esc" key and input "root".

If you see the following information, when you enter the backdoor system already; input the "sysconfig set".
Select 1, and you will see the change password screen.

Comment: Fixed.  For if anyone ever needs this in the future, here's what D-Link sent:


Here are the procedures to enter the backdoor system.
1.Power off the chassis. 
2.Connect the console port correctly.
3.Press the "Esc" key in your keyboard, hold it and not release.
4.Power on the chassis
5.When you see all the LEDs on the chassis light up, release the "Esc" key and input "root".

If you see the following information, when you enter the backdoor system already; input the "sysconfig set".
Select 1, and you will see the change password screen.

Comment: What you can do is put that as an Answer to this question and mark the question as accepted. Right now it'll linger as 'unanswered'. You won't get points for the accepted answer (other than what you get for accepting one), but it'll help others know what fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix from D-Link:

Here are the procedures to enter the backdoor system.

1.Power off the chassis.

2.Connect the console port correctly.

3.Press the "Esc" key in your keyboard, hold it and not release.

4.Power on the chassis

5.When you see all the LEDs on the chassis light up, release the "Esc" key and input "root".

If you see the following information, when you enter the backdoor system already; input the "sysconfig set".
Select 1, and you will see the change password screen.